# Is there a way to disable the Run command dialog in KDE?

Tags: kde

How can i if possible disable the Run command dialog?. It keeps appearing even if *i don't press the Key combination.* ( I have disabled the Key combination ALT+f2)

Disable it as in prevent it from ever running again, *EVER*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the Run Command dialog by creating an custom definition  in the file kdeglobal.

You can find the kdeglobals file under your home dir.

```
#cd  /your-home-dir/.kde/share/config

#vim kdeglobals
```

Add the entry like

```
[KDE Action Restrictions][$i]
run_command=false
```

[Here](http://techbase.kde.org/KDE_System_Administration/Kiosk/Keys) is the help link for kde system admin

Answer (score -1):

Im running KDE at this momemnt, so cant tell you the exact steps,

you can find keyboard shortcuts menu in kde control center,

KDE Control Center -> Accessibility -> Keyboard Shortcuts ...

Try if you have can disable it from there.

Comment: I have disabled it but keeps popping up. I also checked that my keyboard keys aren't stuck.